# Can I create a report that identifies all cases an agent owned or modified throughout a week?

Tags: lightning, reporting, case, service-cloud-console, history-tracking

I would like to create a report in Lightning that identifies all of the cases that a service agent "touched" in the prior week. I'm trying to use the case history field "last edited by," and use the filter "Last edited by" = "Current user," but current user is not available as an option for that filter (in the way I could say Last modified date = TODAY). I've been trying to find a workaround. I tried to create a custom formula field, but case history fields cannot be used in formulas. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have role hierarchy setup at your org, then you can create a role based report. This way, if supervisor accesses the report then he/she can view the subordinate's record under his role hierarchy. Also if, team member access this report and under which no subordinates then he can see his own data.

[image: Case History]

Use, Case Last Modified date in the Date Field as a filter.